# Is it possible to run ASP.NET MVC 3 applications on a Linux based server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Is it possible to install IIS on Linux?

Comment: There is mod_mono for apache to run ASP.NET.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono/6317712#6317712 and use nginx instead of Apache, unless you like port 8082 - FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get IIS running on Linux.

Anyway Linux won't be that awesome if there wasnt a way to get things done!
Have a look at this [Project (Mono-Project)](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support)

This might be a good **alternative** to the IIS.
It is a interpreter and **not a webserver** per se.